# I am adding two arrays using for loop. Only 1st element of my 2nd array is being added to all the elements of 1st array. For loop is not iterating

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, iteration, break

**adding two arrays using for loop. But the second for loop (for k in arr2) is not iterating**

```
from numpy import *
arr1 = array([1,2,3,4])
arr2 = array([3,6,1,8])
arr3 = array([])  #*empty array*

for j in arr1:
    
    for k in arr2: #*this loop is not iterating*
    
       i = k+j 
       arr3 = append(arr3,[i]) 
       
       break     #***break is used so that pointer can again go to first loop***
  
print(arr3)
```

Comment: How do you know that the second for is not iterating? Di you put some print` statements just after the first for and after the second to check which one are executed?

Comment: `break` is wrong here. It is preventing iteration of the inner loop. I don't understand the comment justifying why it's there, but you don't need to manually `break` to go back to the outer loop when the inner is complete.

Comment: whats your expected value of arr3? is it 4,8,4,12? if not then you need to remove "break"

Comment: how can I get [4,8,4,12] ?

Comment: @ShivamSharma you just need one loop that goes through the indices of both arrays (which have the same length) (`for i in range(len(arr1))`), and then add arr1[i] and arr2[i]

Comment: But one thing I dont understand in my code is that why the second loop is not iterating. I have done debugging and can see that the value of k (for k in arr2) is not incrementing. Is it because of break statement? Does break statement prevents the iteration process in nested loops?